[Powershell/MS Outlook]: Add folder to Favorites in Navigation Pane
I want to add a newly generated MAPI Folder to the Favorites Section in the Navigation Pane in Microsoft Outlook.
This is what i tried:
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$pst_name="c:\pathto\Test.pst"

$NameSpace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$NameSpace.AddStore($pst_name)

$olFolder = $NameSpace.Folders.GetLast()
$olNewFolder = $olFolder.Folders.Add("NewFolder")

$olNewFolder.AddToFavorites()

The script runs without erros, and the 'NewFolder' is generated.
However the last line does not sho any effect, and the Folder is not found in the favorites section.
My configuration:

Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0.19045, Build 19045
Microsoft 365
Microsoft (legacy) Outlook 2410 (Build 18129.20158)

Any idea?
Thanks,
BerndGit

Ok. Found already the answer - Faster then expected.
Solution is based on:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1044078/get-list-of-outlook-favorite-item-via-powershell
and
Outlook. Add folder to favorites group
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$pst_name="C:\pathto\Test1123.pst"

$NameSpace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$NameSpace.AddStore($pst_name)

$olFolder = $NameSpace.Folders.GetLast()
$olNewFolder = $olFolder.Folders.Add("NewFolder121")

$ex = $Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer()
$mm = $ex.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(0)
$favorites = $mm.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(4)
$favorites.NavigationFolders.Add($olNewFolder)

